# Smooth Scroll Interfering with Prev and Next on Carousel in Bootstrap 3

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, smooth-scrolling

I was originally having problems with the below JS smooth scroll as it made any real links rather then #location stop working.

```
    $('.navbar-nav > li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).find('>a').prop('hash');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

So I changed it to

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var $target = $(this.hash);
      $target = $target.length && $target
      || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if ($target.length) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $('html,body')
        .animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1200);
       return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Which sorted the original problem of being unable to add a working "blog" link in the navbar however it has now rendered the left and right (next and prev) carousel buttons not working.

I would be grateful if someone can help me out with this as it is driving me crazy.

The html for the carousel is as follows

```
    <section id="main-slider" class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-content">
                    <h1>Responsive Website Design</h1>
                    <p class="lead">With 20% of all website traffic in the UK coming from tablets and smart phones then never before has it been a better time to have a responsive website.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.item-->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-content">
                    <h1>Free Consultation</h1>
                    <p class="lead">I understand every business has different needs so we can discuss what it is your want to achieve and using my expert advice make it a reality.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.item-->
        <div class="item">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-content">
                    <h1>Built to be SEO/Google Friendly</h1>
                    <p class="lead">Having a website built is the first step but next you need to put it in front of your target audience. On site SEO is where it all begins.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.item-->
    </div><!--/.carousel-inner-->
    <a class="prev" href="#main-slider" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
    <a class="next" href="#main-slider" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
</section><!--/#main-slider-->
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the answers above are correct. I just wanted to spell it out a little clearer for anyone needing help.

The code that needs to be updated is the `SmoothScroll` function itself. You will need to know the ID of the carousel from your bootstrap page. Just add the carousel ID to the `not().click` function and it will work like a charm. Here is an example of what I did. The change was made on the third line of code, where you see the carousel `ID#`.

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#carousel-299058])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 70
        }, 500);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

`$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {`

with:

`$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#media])').click(function () {`

Happy coding!

Comment: media is the carousel id

Answer (score 0):

I was using the smooth scrolling javascript everyone uses and having the same issue, like all obedient little developers out there I was using `#myCarousel`:

```
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
```

and as soon as I changed `[href=media]` to `[href=myCarousel]` my Bootstrap carousel controls started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and my solution was to use a class on each link as opposed to the href attribute selectors within the jQuery function.

This does mean a little extra HTML mark-up but I felt it was more robust and causes less interference with additional scripts that may be added within your project.

**So this:**

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
```

**Becomes this:**

```
$('.your-class-name').click(function() {
```

**And any smooth scrolling links you add to your page will become:**

```
<a href="#section" class="your-class-name">Link</a>
```

**And scroll to:**

```
<div id="section">... Content ...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to add : \\. It is necessary to add it since the latest version of JQUERY.

```
$('a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#carousel-299058])').click(function() {
```